# How to create flutter local notification custom layout

Tags: flutter

Hello Guys I'm trying many example of flutter local notification custom layout but i can't set my UI design. Please help me for below UI design.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As of now, flutter local notification does not provide a custom layout notification that seems very unlikely to have that kind of support reason being custom notification depends on the native view. (i.e. XML layout files on Android and a view controller on iOS)

**If you want to use a custom layout then you need to write your own native code and use it in flutter (via Methods channel).**